# Groovy script getting only specific values of the key

Tags: dictionary, groovy

```
def mymap = [name:"raju", likes:"cheese", name:"dinesh", likes :"ice"]

def x = mymap.find{ it.key == "likes" }.value

println x
```

I need to get all the values of the key likes.

Expected answer : cheese, ice
But the above code only getting ice

Comment: you can't have a map with duplicate keys. period.

Answer (score 1):

Keys in maps must be unique (think of them as like an address), so in your line:

```
def mymap = [name:"raju", likes:"cheese", name:"dinesh", likes :"ice"]
```

The second `likes` is overwriting the first

To have multiple values for a key, you can use a list as the value

```
def mymap = [name: "raju", likes: ["cheese", "ice"], name: "dinesh"]
```

And then:

```
def x = mymap.find{ it.key == "likes" }.value

println x
```

Will print `["cheese", "ice"]` as expected

As an aside, you can replace `mymap.find{ it.key == "likes" }.value` with `mymap["likes"]` or even `mymap.likes`